# Accessing CruiseControl.NET project name in NAnt

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

CCNet passes the current build label to NAnt via the NAnt property "CCNetLabel". Is there a similar property where it passes the name of the CCNet project name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. The NAnt property is "CCNetProject".